# Filtering and rounding values in slider

Tags: r, shiny

I am following this [Mastering Shiny tutorial](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html) and trying to replicate the example. I have the following code, (same content but different data).

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


value <- c(1000, 1111, 1200, 1300, 10.8293485923485, 2000, 3435, 4423.928039457293, 2345, 3453)
total <- c(100, 111, 120, 130, 11.9873452938475, 200, 234, 124, 654.8934923845, 112)
dataf <- data.frame(value, total)

make_ui <- function(x, var) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    rng <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    sliderInput(var, var, min = rng[1], max = rng[2], value = rng)
  } else if (is.factor(x)) {
    levs <- levels(x)
    selectInput(var, var, choices = levs, selected = levs, multiple = TRUE)
  } else {
    # Not supported
    NULL
  }
}

filter_var <- function(x, val) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    !is.na(x) & x >= val[1] & x <= val[2]
  } else if (is.factor(x)) {
    x %in% val
  } else {
    # No control, so don't filter
    TRUE
  }
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      make_ui(dataf$value, "Value"),
      make_ui(dataf$total, "Total")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected <- reactive({
    filter_var(dataf$value, input$value) &
      filter_var(dataf$total, input$total)
  })
  
output$data <- renderTable(head(dataf[selected(), ], 6))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have two questions here:

- Why the filtering is not working? I cannot see the data table too.
- How to round the values in the Slider (e.g. 10.83 instead of 10.8293485923485)?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter does not work as you named your inputs `Total` and `Value` whereas you refer to `total` and `value`. To round the limits to 2 digits I would suggest to use `floor` and `ceiling` as simple rounding may drop the limits:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


value <- c(1000, 1111, 1200, 1300, 10.8293485923485, 2000, 3435, 4423.928039457293, 2345, 3453)
total <- c(100, 111, 120, 130, 11.9873452938475, 200, 234, 124, 654.8934923845, 112)
dataf <- data.frame(value, total)

make_ui <- function(x, var) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    rng <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    rng <- c(floor(100 * rng[1]) / 100, ceiling(100 * rng[2]) / 100)
    sliderInput(var, var, min = rng[1], max = rng[2], value = rng)
  } else if (is.factor(x)) {
    levs <- levels(x)
    selectInput(var, var, choices = levs, selected = levs, multiple = TRUE)
  } else {
    # Not supported
    NULL
  }
}

filter_var <- function(x, val) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    !is.na(x) & x >= val[1] & x <= val[2]
  } else if (is.factor(x)) {
    x %in% val
  } else {
    # No control, so don't filter
    TRUE
  }
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      make_ui(dataf$value, "Value"),
      make_ui(dataf$total, "Total")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected <- reactive({
    filter_var(dataf$value, input$Value) &
      filter_var(dataf$total, input$Total)
  })

  output$data <- renderTable(
    head(dataf[selected(), ], 6)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]